# Removing whitespace between " " with regex

Tags: regex, url, whitespace

I have hundreds of links with whitespaces in it, example: url="http://example.com/media/local/test-example ready for whitespace.doc"

What do I want is to remove the whitespaces and replace it with "-" (minus only). The replacement I'll do by my self in visual studio but I couldn't figure it out, how to match only the whitespaces between the " ".

I've tried so many things but this is the most appropiate I think is \"(.*)\"

EDIT: I forgot that it must include url="example.com/media/local/test-example ready for whitespace.doc". Because if don't have this, it matches all spaces in files between " ". Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/Px9vnd/1

Comment: @WiktorStribzew, thank you for your answer, is very good but my is my fault that I forgot that it must include url="http://example.com/media/local/test-example ready for whitespace.doc". Because if don't have this, it matches all spaces in files between " ". Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Can't you plainly use `Regex.Replace(text,"\"[^\"]*\"", x => x.Value.Replace(" ", "-"))`?